# How can I make tableViewController know about managedObjectContext changed outside?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

In the app I'm developing I've got 2 *tableViewControllers* with tables filled with the data using Core Data and 2 *ViewControllers* in which I can read, add, delete and update that information. Everything is great with this except the fact that *tableViewControllers* don't get updated. I was thinking about using delegation to somehow make those *tableViews* know that *didChangeObject* happened in another *ViewController* but I really don't know how to do it and I'm not sure that this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what the `NSFetchedResultsController` is designed for.  You use the `NSFetchedResultsController` to drive the data for your table views and make your table view controller a delegate to the `NSFetchedResultsController` to receive updates about when the data changes.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use `NSFetchedResultsController` as **Marcus** post.It is good to work with tableview.

If you do not want to use it,you can use notification

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(managedObjectDidChange:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
```

Then merge change

```
-(void)managedObjectDidChange:(NSNotification *)nofication{
[self.context performBlock:^{
    [self.context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:nofication];
}];
}
```